# Getting ORA-01031: insufficient privileges while querying a table instead of ORA-00942: table or view does not exist

Tags: oracle, privileges

When I'm querying a table in schema C from schema A, I'm getting **ORA-01031: insufficient privileges** and when I'm querying the same table from schema B, I'm getting **ORA-00942: table or view does not exist**. On the table neither of the schemas are having any privileges. Why am I getting different error messages in this case?

Comment: Which schema does the table actually exist in; are there any synonyms for the table (private in any schema, or public); and are privileges on the table granted to a role which either schema has granted? Just looking for privileges granted directly to the schema (user) doesn't tell the whole story.

Comment: The table exists in a third schema C. There are no synonyms for that table. Select access is granted to a role but neither A nor B are granted that role.

Comment: OK, so look at the differences in the roles and privileges granted to A and B. It looks like A will have visibility of the data dictionary (`select any dictionary` perhaps), so it can see that the table exists; but still doesn't have `select` privileges on it?

Comment: In schema A when I run `SELECT * FROM SYS.ALL_OBJECTS T WHERE T.OBJECT_NAME = <Table Name>`, its not returning anything.

Answer (score 13):

You may get `ORA-01031: insufficient privileges` instead of `ORA-00942: table or view does not exist` when you have at least one privilege on the table, but not the necessary privilege.

**Create schemas**

```
SQL> create user schemaA identified by schemaA;

User created.

SQL> create user schemaB identified by schemaB;

User created.

SQL> create user test_user identified by test_user;

User created.

SQL> grant connect to test_user;

Grant succeeded.
```

**Create objects and privileges**

It is unusual, but possible, to grant a schema a privilege like DELETE without granting SELECT.

```
SQL> create table schemaA.table1(a number);

Table created.

SQL> create table schemaB.table2(a number);

Table created.

SQL> grant delete on schemaB.table2 to test_user;

Grant succeeded.
```

**Connect as TEST_USER and try to query the tables**

This shows that having *some* privilege on the table changes the error message.

```
SQL> select * from schemaA.table1;
select * from schemaA.table1
                      *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00942: table or view does not exist


SQL> select * from schemaB.table2;
select * from schemaB.table2
                      *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01031: insufficient privileges


SQL>
```

Comment: My user is already added in ORA_DBA

Comment: What if I have a role (RoleA) that has select table privileges, and i grant that role SELECT option to SchemaA.table1. And then i set the same role to test_user. Can test_user not query that schemaA.table1? or how do we provision such for a table or at the Schema level that all tables under this shema can be SELECTable?

Comment: @Ak777 You can certainly grant these privileges through roles. Unfortunately, you must loop through all the objects in a schema and grant the privileges individually. I usually do this with a PL/SQL script. But the hard part is remembering to always run that script whenever new objects are created. There's no single schema-level grant command until Oracle version 23c.

Comment: Thanks for your response. great to know that its there although at a more recent. Higher versions only. we are currently using 19c and mostly at some point in time, would move/upgrade.

Answer (score 3):

for ORA-01031: insufficient privileges. Some of the more common causes are:

1. You tried to change an Oracle username or password without having the appropriate privileges.
2. You tried to perform an `UPDATE` to a table, but you only have `SELECT` access to the table.
3. You tried to start up an Oracle database using `CONNECT INTERNAL`.
4. You tried to install an Oracle database without having the appropriate privileges to the operating-system.

The option(s) to resolve this Oracle error are:

1. You can have the Oracle DBA grant you the appropriate privileges that you are missing.
2. You can have the Oracle DBA execute the operation for you.
3. If you are having trouble starting up Oracle, you may need to add the Oracle user to the dba group.

For `ORA-00942: table or view does not exist.` You tried to execute a SQL statement that references a table or view that either does not exist, that you do not have access to, or that belongs to another schema and you didn't reference the table by the schema name.

If this error occurred because the table or view does not exist, you will need to create the table or view.

You can check to see if the table exists in Oracle by executing the following SQL statement:

```
select *
from all_objects
where object_type in ('TABLE','VIEW')
and object_name = 'OBJECT_NAME';
```

For example, if you are looking for a suppliers table, you would execute:

```
select *
from all_objects
where object_type in ('TABLE','VIEW')
and object_name = 'SUPPLIERS';
```

OPTION #2

If this error occurred because you do not have access to the table or view, you will need to have the owner of the table/view, or a DBA grant you the appropriate privileges to this object.

OPTION #3

If this error occurred because the table/view belongs to another schema and you didn't reference the table by the schema name, you will need to rewrite your SQL to include the schema name.

For example, you may have executed the following SQL statement:

```
select *
from suppliers;
```

But the `suppliers` table is not owned by you, but rather, it is owned by a schema called app, you could fix your SQL as follows:

```
select *
from app.suppliers;
```

If you do not know what schema the suppliers table/view belongs to, you can execute the following SQL to find out:

```
select owner
from all_objects
where object_type in ('TABLE','VIEW')
and object_name = 'SUPPLIERS';
```

This will return the schema name who owns the suppliers table.

Answer (score 2):

`ORA-01031: insufficient privileges` happens when the object exists in the schema but do not have any access to that object.

`ORA-00942: table or view does not exist` happens when the object does not exist in the current schema. If the object exists in another schema, you need to access it using .. Still you can get insufficient privileges error if the owner has not given access to the calling schema.

Answer (score 2):

try to execute this on sql command line:

```
connect/ as sysdba;
create user b identified by "password"; 
grant all privileges to b;
```

and go create a new connection in SQL Developer;

do the same for schema 'c';

and grant privileges for schema 'a' too:

```
connect/ as sysdba;
grant all privileges to a;
```

this method fixed the problem for me.

Answer (score -1):

In SQL Developer: Everything was working fine and I had all the permissions to login and there was no password change and I could click the table and see the data tab.

But when I run query (simple select statement) it was showing "ORA-01031: insufficient privileges" message.

The solution is simply disconnect the connection and reconnect. 
Note: only doing Reconnect did not work for me.
[SQL Developer Disconnect Snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tSEX5.png)

Answer (score -1):

**ORA-01031: insufficient privileges**
Solution: Go to Your System User.
then Write This Code:

SQL> grant dba to UserName; //Put This username which user show this error message.

Grant succeeded.