# error: ORA-01031: insufficient privileges

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have a problem.

```
CREATE TABLE accounts(
  id INTEGER, 
  name VARCHAR2(100)
)
/

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION account_balance(account_id_in IN accounts.id%TYPE)
RETURN NUMBER
IS
BEGIN
  RETURN 0;
END;
/
```

Error:

```
Error starting at line : 1 in command -
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION account_balance(account_id_in IN accounts.id%TYPE)
RETURN NUMBER
IS
BEGIN
  RETURN 0;
END;
Error report -
ORA-01031: insufficient privileges
01031. 00000 -  "insufficient privileges"
*Cause:    An attempt was made to perform a database operation without
           the necessary privileges.
*Action:   Ask your database administrator or designated security
           administrator to grant you the necessary privileges
```

[image]

Please help me resolve above error, thank you!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20988572/getting-ora-01031-insufficient-privileges-while-querying-a-table-instead-of-ora

Comment: dude, no accepted answer exist.

Comment: The issue is pretty clear.  Talk to the DBA to get the permissions to create a function.

Comment: In this case, How DBA set permission to create function(s)?

Comment: @dovy: Are you the DBA?

Comment: I am DBA (when I use other account), this is my localhost. I have full permissions. I need creating function, procedures.

Comment: I believe the syntax is `grant create procedure to your_user` or something close to that., where you would replace `your_user` with the user you are logged in as that doesn't have the required privileges.  Make sure you run this from the account that does have full permissions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As pointed out in the comments, you are missing the required permissions to create the function from whatever user account you are currently using.

Let's assume your less privileged login is called `some_user`. To fix your problem, login as your more privileged account, and apply the following `GRANT` statement:

```
grant create procedure to some_user;
```

Documentation: [GRANT](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/statements_9013.htm)

> [`CREATE PROCEDURE`](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/statements_9013.htm#sthref6786): Create stored procedures, **functions**, and packages in the grantee's schema.

Answer (score 0):

Login as

```
sys as sysdba
```

then execute the following command after changing username to your username

```
GRANT CREATE PROCEDURE TO username;
```

Answer (score 0):

Do like this

```
sqlplus /nolog
connect sys/"123456a@"@xe as sysdba

SQl> alter session set "_ORACLE_SCRIPT"=true;
SQL>grant create table to donhuvy;
```